# Node.js multiple printing to console without a newline

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an app for upload files to my server, I am using `fs` and stream my file to the server and use Chuck data for keep tracking file upload progress.

Here sample code for uploading:

```
// upload video
function uploadVideo(url,file,callback) {
    let size = fs.lstatSync(file).size;
    let bytes = 0;
    let formData = {
      file: fs.createReadStream(file).on('data', (chunk) => {
        bytes += chunk.length
        process.stdout.write(file+filesize(bytes).human()+' of '+filesize(size).human()+' Uploaded'+"\r")
      }),
    };

    request.post({url:url, json:true, formData: formData}, function optionalCallback(err, httpResponse, body) {
      if (err) {
        return callback('upload failed:', err);
      }
      callback(null,body);
    });

}
```

as you can see I am using `process.stdout.write` for showing upload progress without newline and its work fine.

The problem I have when I am uploading multiple files same time, all upload progress get override in one line, I want each upload progress be in separate line.

Multiple upload example:

```
let files = ['video-1.mp4','video-2.mp4','video-3.mp4','video-4.mp4','video-5.mp4']

// upload multiple file
files.forEach((file) => {
    uploadVideo(url,file,function(err,output){
        console.log(output)
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a package called `multi-progress` [multi-progress](https://github.com/pitaj/multi-progress).
it does exactly what I want.

Answer (score 1):

There is a package for that: [node-progress](https://github.com/visionmedia/node-progress)

It gives you something like this:

```
downloading [=====             ] 39/bps 29% 3.7s
```

Comment: I tested this, still, same problem here is a [demo](https://imgur.com/a/IWmrw) , its show all progress bar in one line.